# Delete a word in string

Tags: c#, string

I Get list of files listed in a folder called Book like this

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("Book");
```

and I put these files name as button texts in my app . buttons texts get like this :

```
Book\1.mp3
book\2.mp3
```

I want to remove this `Book\` from texts. How can I do that?

Comment: How have you tried so far to solve that problem? Have you checked the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get to the names:

```
string[] files = new DirectoryInfo("Book").GetFiles().Select(f => f.Name).ToArray();
```

I don't know how much overhead getting the directoryinfo really would introduce. But if it seems overkill as suggested you can use `Path.GetFileName`.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want the filename then you can use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Path.GetFileName to get the file name from the path. Here is the example

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(@"Book\1.mp3");
```

here in `filename` you will get **1.mp3**

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the directory is always called "Book":

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("Book").Select(f => f.Substring(5));
```

This will strip out the beginning of the text ("Book\") leaving you with just the file name itself.

Comment: I did not downvote, but this answer is too rigid for me. John's answer is more durable.

Answer (score -1):

As you got the names from Directory.GetFiles so the return list is obviously file paths. You can separate the file name from a path or relative path using following api

```
string name = Path.GetFileName(@"\Book\test.mp3");
```

it will give you `test.mp3` in return. See detail about [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I think it should *at least* explain what `GetFileName` does generally and how to find more information on `GetFileName`. To become really useful, it should probably also contain some information on how you found `GetFileName`, why you chose it, as opposed to other available methods, and whether it solves all cases that could be titled "Delete a word in string", or rather a specific class of cases (in which case, again, an explanation is required why this question describes a specific case rather than the general one).

Answer (score -2):

```
using Replace funciton

 files[0].Replace("Book\","");
    files[1].Replace("Book\","");

Use for loop
```

Comment: An answer with code for copy and pasting without any explanations may help the OP in their current question, but probably does not help them understand *how* this problem, and similar problems, can be solved. This is even more true for future visitors with similar, but not the same problem, who cannot benefit from a copy-and-paste answer at all.